# Navigation Drawer doesn't show fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I've created a new Android Studio Project and my MainActivity is a Navigation Drawer Activity.

So, I can't show up fragments. I've read many post on internet and here too.

Explaining:

I open navigation drawer, select menu "Podcast".
PodcastsFragment should be shown, but it still showing activity.

[image: MainActivity]

[image]

**MainActivity code:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Tracker mTracker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // [START shared_tracker]
        // Obtain the shared Tracker instance.
        AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
        mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
        // [END shared_tracker]

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.i("TESTE", "Setting screen name: " + "teste");
        mTracker.setScreenName("Main " + "teste");
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.                                                                                                        
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentTransaction ft = null;




        if (id == R.id.nav_podcasts) {
            Log.d("Clicked:", "nav_podcasts");
            fragment = new PodcastsFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_feed) {
            //fragment = new FeedFragment();
            Log.d("Clicked:", "nav_feed");
            //fragment = new FeedFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            FeedFragment ff = new FeedFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_body, ff);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_downloads) {
            //fragment = new DownloadsFragment();
            Log.d("Clicked:", "nav_downloads");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_add) {
            //fragment = new OPMLFragment();
            Log.d("Clicked:", "nav_add");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            //fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            Log.d("Clicked:", "nav_settings");
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**PodcastsFragment code:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PodcastsFragment extends Fragment {

    public PodcastsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_podcasts, container, false);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_podcasts, container, false);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

**app_bar_main code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.test.test.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>



    <!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**activity_main code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**content_main code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context="com.test.test.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="teste"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Log "Clicked]

Comment: You have no `ViewGroup` with ID `container_body` to hold the `Fragment`s in your posted layouts.

Comment: Hi, thx for the help. I've added a new layout that I forgot to upload.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what isn't working, and where in the code it's failing.

Comment: So, I click at nav drawer menu item, like, podcast, for example. It should open PodcastsFragment, but it don't show the fragment. Logs don't show errors.

Comment: What about your `"Clicked:"` log print? Have you debugged to check if `PodcastsFragment`'s `onCreateView()` method is running? Also, you probably want the `content_main` `<include>` in `activity_main`, instead of `app_bar_main`.

Comment: activity_main includes app_bar_main which includes content_main, is there any difference?

Comment: you are wrong use of fragment in code....

Comment: try this github code https://github.com/larsjuh/Android-Navigation-Drawer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/youtube/demo/youtubedemo/MainActivity.java

Comment: and also watch this video on youtube....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tguOfRD8vYo

Comment: if you don't understand than i again try

Comment: I'll try it and let you know later today. Thanks.

Comment: @ExceptionLover Hey man, great thanks. I've followed tutorial and it worked fine. Please, answer the question then I can mark it as answered. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the  drawer's list in Your activity and add setOnItemClickListener().When the user selects an item in the drawer's list, the system calls onItemClick() on the OnItemClickListener given to setOnItemClickListener().

What you do in the onItemClick() method depends on how you've implemented your app structure. In the following example, selecting each item in the list inserts a different Fragment into the main content view (the FrameLayout element identified by the R.id.content_frame ID):
for more delail please read these articles [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tguOfRD8vYo) and [github example](https://github.com/larsjuh/Android-Navigation-Drawer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/youtube/demo/youtubedemo/MainActivity.java)

Answer (score 1):

**Latest** - If you use [Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#top_of_page), then you don't have to manually connect your fragments to your drawer MenuItem. `The system will automatically tie you MenuItem to specific fragment` If the id of the MenuItem in your `menu/xyz_menu.xml` matches the id of the destination in `navigation/xyz_nav.xml`, the NavController can then navigate to that destination.

Follow the correct steps mentioned in the official documentation : https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer

**Note :**

1. They have a [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationBasicSample) linked to the same article which you can refer.
2. To get this is effect, do not implement `onNavigationItemSelected` otherwise it will override the system let you handle the navigation.