# Android - Navigation Up With Fragment

Tags: android, android-toolbar, back-button

I have an Activity with 3 Fragments (Login, Register, Terms)

The Login Fragment show up into the activity, if i click into the register button, i need to show a back button into the toolbar to make that action.

I didn't implemented nothing yet... Can someone help me to build it?

My activity have only a Framelayout to insert the fragments... I need to put something else here? Or i'll change only the back-end code?

**Activity xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_initial"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I'm lost...

Comment: this answer on stackoverflow... http://stackoverflow.com/a/37085318/3678308

Comment: and also post your code in your queston...