# send data from activity to activity class and between them fragment

Tags: android

My app show activity(1) .when you press button ,app open fragment .After that , fragment send data to activity (2) and open activity (2) -that works well- . Finally ,activity(2) edit the data and send it to activity(1) -here is problem- .

I have tried many ways but it doesn't work

Comment: It'll be difficult to help without seeing some code.

Comment: which ways have you tried??? / what data type are you passing between activities?? custom classes?

Comment: try this answer on stackoverflow... http://stackoverflow.com/a/37085318/3678308

Answer (score 2):

When you are working with complex screens like multiple fragments and activities, I would recommend you to just use an event-driven library, like:

- [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)
- [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)
- [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/The-RxJava-Android-Module)

---

It's going to let you transform this:

[image: No EventBus]

into this:

[image: With EventBus]

---

Check [this post](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/event-driven-programming-for-android-part-i-f5ea4a3c4eab#.igx7bnc5m) for a detailed explanation about the use cases of these libraries.

Comment: I strongly support EventBus. It's awesome.

Comment: @Evin1_    I don't change any thing in mainefast or gradle except add compile .                                                                                                  I use otto . My problem is I can't use any method inside subscribber method . Even I can't write getmsg.message = my_varible ;                                          I use this way https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVqBmGK3VuA

Answer (score 0):

May be like this;

In fragment:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("data", data);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

In activity(2):

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("data", data);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

And in activity(1):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
     // Make sure the request was successful
         if (resultCode == Acitivity.RESULT_OK) {
             String stringData = data.getExtras().getString("data"); 
             // Data can be string, int etc. or serializable
             // YourObject object = (YourObject) data.getExtras().getSerializable("data");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey than try with EventBus. I recommend it too.

Comment: I think the problem is OnActicityResult() doesn't work well

Comment: By the way if you are sure problem is in onActivityResult(), I edited onActivityResult(). If data is a object than make sure object class implements Serializable interface